# Cannot update boolean column with Rails 5.0.1 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `Diary`, which has column `is_draft` (boolean, null: false).
I set it enum scope like `is_draft: { draft: true, published: false }` .

When I execute this in rails console,

```
Diary.last.update!(is_draft: false)
```

It create a query like this, and fails:

```
UPDATE `diaries` SET `is_draft` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2018-08-22 16:39:17' WHERE `diaries`.`id` = 66

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'is_draft' cannot be null
```

On the other hand, this succeeds.

```
Diary.last.update!(is_draft: true)
```

How can I update it to false?

Comment: Are you using the `nilify_blanks` or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

In your tests, you are trying to update a `false` value or a `true` value ?

From a true, try :

```
Diary.last.update_attributes(is_draft: false)
```

Comment: `Diary.last.update_attributes(is_draft: false)` creates the same query, and fails.

Comment: @Taichi, are you trying to do the command from a false value or a true value ? (check with this in command line : Diary.last.is_draft)

Comment: @Taichi can you show me how you have created field is_draft on your model

Comment: try this:
enum is_draft: { draft: 0, published: 1 }
Diary.last.update! is_draft: 0